# How do I remove an attribute from an ElementTree Element?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a simple XML object `<person>` created with [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

```
<person name='John' age='21' />
```

I want to modify the XML element to remove the `age` attribute.

```
<person name='John' />
```

I can access the attribute using [`.get("age")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.get), but using [`.remove("age")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.remove) results in a TypeError.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree

xml = ElementTree.Element('person', name="john", age="21")
xml.remove("age") 
# TypeError: remove() argument must be xml.etree.ElementTree.Element, not str
```

[According to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.remove), `.remove()` can only be used to remove subelements. There doesn't seem to be any alternative option for removing attributes.

**How can I remove an XML attribute from an `xml.etree.ElementTree` object?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `del xml.attrib["age"]`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree

xml = ElementTree.Element('person', Name="john", age="21")
print(xml.items())
del xml.attrib["age"]
print(xml.items())
```

Will produce:

```
[('Name', 'john'), ('age', '21')]
[('Name', 'john')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `xml.attrib.pop("age")`.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

xml = ElementTree.Element('person', name="john", age="21")
print(ElementTree.tostring(xml).decode())

xml.attrib.pop("age")
print(ElementTree.tostring(xml).decode())
```

Output:

```
<person name='John' age='21' />
<person name='John' />
```

Explanation:

The `attrib` member of `ElementTree` is implemented as a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) object, meaning you can use any standard dictionary methods on it.